# Oracle SQL SELECT in loop

Tags: sql, oracle, variables, loops, for-loop

Hidiho,

I have a bunch of data from elecrticity meters. It's values are taken every hour for a whole year. 
Now i want to get them added and shown for every month. So that I get a table from Jan to Dec and its summed energyinformation. The Date-Type is `"DD.MM.YYYY HH24"`.

Can I loop through the data and show every month in an extra table?

In Pseudo-Code it should look something like this:

```
For x in 1..12 loop
  SELECT energie, time FROM tbl_energie
  WHERE time  LIKE '%.0' + x + '.12%'     --(01.x.2012)
end loop;
```

Thanks for your help - Phips

Comment: Is there a reason why you are not using a `DATE` type for your `time` column?

Answer (score 1):

It's a little clunky, and it won't work too well in high performance code, but how about something like:

```
select sum(energie), time
from (
  select energie, to_char(time, 'MM.YYYY') as time
  from tbl_energie
)
group by time
order by time
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your time is stored as a string, you have two choices:  either do string manipulation or convert to date/time.

Lets do this as string manipulation:

```
select substr(time, 4, 7), sum(energie)
from tbl_energie
group by substring(time, 4, 7)
order by 1
```

I would suggest that you also verify that you have meter readings on every hour, before believing the results.